# Configure vim for text selection with shift and copy/paste via ctrl+c, ctrl+v?

Tags: vim

Many machines i need to work with have basic NIX installation with vim as text editor. But vim's way to select text is kind of unusual to me :). Is it any easy way to re-configure vim so it will use <kbd>shift</kbd> in order to select text and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> / <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> for copy and paste?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Add the following lines to your `_vimrc` or `.vimrc`

```
source $VIMRUNTIME/mswin.vim
behave mswin
```

But beware, visual mode is then CTRL-Q instead of CTRL-V.

For an overview what mswin.vim does see the 
[mswin.vim sourcode](http://vim.cybermirror.org/runtime/mswin.vim).
It is commented very well and if some command is unclear you can easily look it up in 
vim's help.

Here is a quick overview compile from the source:

> - backspace and cursor keys wrap to previous/next line
> - CTRL-X and SHIFT-Del are Cut
> - CTRL-C and CTRL-Insert are Copy
> - CTRL-V and SHIFT-Insert are Paste
> - Use CTRL-Q to do what CTRL-V used to do
> - Use CTRL-S for saving, also in Insert mode
> - CTRL-Z is Undo; not in cmdline though
> - CTRL-Y is Redo (although not repeat); not in cmdline though
> - Alt-Space is System menu
> - CTRL-A is Select all
> - CTRL-Tab is Next window
> - CTRL-F4 is Close window

Comment: What else this option reconfigures?

Comment: Thanks, that partially works. But on some platforms ctrl+v still don't insert - it just draws a blue '^' O_O.

Comment: @softly.lt: Added to the answer.

Comment: @Eye of Hell: This is the expected behaviour if mswin.vim is not active, but it's difficult to say why without further information.

Comment: The source link is broken; here's where I found it: https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/runtime/mswin.vim . Hopefully the same file.